# USB serial port open error - 'the parameter is incorrect' on win8

Tags: c++

i have installed TIVA USB virtual com port on WIN8 PC and opening it with c++(boost lib) application. it is giving error 'The parameter is incorrect'. but same is opening on WIN7 without any error.

i notice there is a difference in version of usbscr.sys driver on WIN7 and WIN8

please suggest if any one solved this type issue with USB com ports

Thanks inadvance